# What is the package name to install pam-pwdfile via yum on Red Hat?

Tags: redhat, ftp, pam

I am installing vsftpd and want to create virtual users. I want to have a file and add users to it via htpasswd and use it for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick googling shows there is no official package for it yet but you can build your own RPM package using an RPM spec file provided in pam-pwdfile source tarball (it's [here](https://code.google.com/p/pam-pwdfile/source/browse/trunk/contrib/pam-pwdfile.spec) in their source code repo).